# Error when execute sed comand with tcl

Tags: sed, tcl

The file that I use contains lines like following:

```
first0.1.second1.1.third1 
first0.1.second2.2.third1
first0.n.second2.n.third1
```

I want to replace ".n." with "{j}" // n belong to [1-100]

So the desired lines are like the following:

```
first0.{j}.second1.{j}.third1 
first0.{j}.second2.{j}.third1
```

I use the following command under tcl

```
exec sed -i 's/\.[1-9]\./\.{j}\./g' file
```

but I got

```
invalid command name "1-9"
```

How can I do this substitution?

Comment: Note that dots are not special in the replacement string and don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 5):

Brace your expressions...

Single quotes are not quoting mechanism for `Tcl`, so brace your `awk` expressions as,

```
exec sed -i {s/\.[1-9]\./\.{j}\./g} file
```

**Reference :**  [Frequently Made Mistakes in Tcl](http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.lang.tcl/fmm.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that in plain Tcl:

```
set filename "file"

set fh [open $filename r]
set data [read -nonewline $fh]
close $fh

set fh [open $filename w]
puts $fh [regsub -all {\.\d\.} $data {.{j}.}]
close $fh

exec cat $filename
```

```
first0.{j}.second1.{j}.third1 
first0.{j}.second2.{j}.third1
```